# How can i detect the app update state, so that i can remove all local storage data by ionic and angular js?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

When user try to reinstall the app's without uninstalling the existing one. Then app's need to remove all the local-storage/session data, so that user need to login again.

Can anybody help me regarding this issue , how to detect this re-installing stage by IONIC or Angular js ?

Answer (score -1):

Consider you stored some data in following variable.

localStorage.data = "some data";

Once you reinstall app without uninstall it will be still there in that same variable.

so better you write a code like this.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(localStorage.data == null){
       localStorage.data = "";
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

But, i need to remove all the localstorage data when it reinstall. So, i think your provided code will not remove all localstorage data during reinstallation.
So, can you help me how to remove all data during reinstallation ?

Comment: localstorage data will vanish only you uninstall the app, if u reinstall the app on top of existing without uninstall, localstorage data will be there. we can't remove data while reinstall. functionally you can do this, so once app is open, you call above function so that it will remove all data..plz upload your app.js code If you still facing the problem,

Comment: You told me that when app will be open then your code will remove the localstorage data. But i need those data. I want to remove only when app will reinstall. Thanks for your cooperation #raj peer